# jquery templates: How to create a template for unknown type

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I just started looking at the jquery-tmpl and was wondering if it would be possible to create a template that would render an unknown type. Basically a generic template that would take a JSON object and render all of values found on the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the each template tag

```
{{each(key, value) jsonObject}}
  <p>${key}: ${value}</p>
{{/each}}
```